# Solving $7^{2x}\cdot4^{x-2}=11^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am trying to solve this equation but I am stuck little bit right now. This is how I did it:
$$
7^{2x}\cdot4^{x-2}=11^x\\
\text{log both sides}\\
\log(7^{2x}\cdot4^{x-2})=\log(11^x)\\
\log(7^{2x}) + \log(4^{x-2})=\log(11^x)\\
2x\log(7) + (x-2)\log (4)=x\log (11)\\
\text{I got this far}\\
$$

Can somebody give me idea, am I on right track, and if I am, how can I solve it further. Thanks.

Comment: Just group terms containing $x$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've done most of it.  Next you get
$$
x(2\log7+\log4) -2\log4 = x\log11,
$$
and so
$$
x(2\log7+\log4-\log11) = 2\log4
$$
etc.

Answer (score 3):

Your almost done, you just need to collect the $x$-terms:
$$2x\log(7)+x\log(4)-2\log(4)-x\log(11)=0$$
$$x(2\log(7)+\log(4)-\log(11))=2\log4$$
$$x=\frac{2\log(4)}{2\log(7)+\log(4)-\log(11)}$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are on the right track. Now just collect the terms with $x$ in it on one side and the constant on the other side. You should get
$$
x(2\log(7) + \log(4) - \log(11)) = 2\log(4) \\
x = \frac{2\log(4)}{2\log(7) + \log(4) - \log(11)}.
$$